# Warning for a cast from a char literal to a char *

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I can't find a warning for the following in Visual Studio. I turned on /Wall but still get nothing:

```
const char * pointer = '\0';
```

gcc won't compile it for C++11, C++14, or C++17:

> [x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

gcc will compile with the above as a warning if I pass `-fpermissive`:

> [x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

clang won't compile for C++11, C++14, or C++17:

> [x86-64 clang 5.0.0 #1] error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'const char *' with an rvalue of type 'char'

I'm asking because of the below code that ended up in our codebase, apparently with no warnings:

```
std::ofstream file;
//...
file.write('\0', 20);
```

Is there a way to turn on a warning for this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 only allows this conversion with const values of '\0'. Examples:

```
char c = '\0';
const char cconst = '\0';

const char * p1 = c;      //error (not even warning)
const char * p2 = cconst; //ok
const char * p3 = '\0';   //ok
const char * p4 = '\1';   //error (not even warning)
```

The specific error is:

> Error: a value of type "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char *"

Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41) gives a warning with C++03 but an error with C++11 and later. The behavior was changed sometime between the Feb. 28, 2011 (draft N3242 and May 15, 2013 (draft N3690). I can't find the exact point.

In earlier drafts of C++, such as n1905, the OP code is defined as a valid conversion:

> **A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null
>   pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type;** the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable
>   from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type. Two null pointer values of the same type shall
>   compare equal. **The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion,** and not
>   the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).

Section 3.9.1.2 defines the signed integer types:

> There are five signed integer types: **“signed char”**, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”.

This was changed in later drafts. In draft N3690 from 2013, section 4.10 says:

> **A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type;** the result is the null pointer value of that type
>   and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion
>   is called a null pointer conversion. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. **The
>   conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion,** and not the
>   sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).

`character-literal` is a defined as a literal in section 2.14.1, but it does not appear in section 2.14.2. Instead it gets its own section - 2.14.3.

C++17 draft n4659 has the exact same verbiage but in different sections.

I don't see a way to give a warning for this in VS 2015. This would be another reason to run static analysis tools / other compilers to catch extra warnings.

Thanks to @EricPostpischil for the help.